# How to assign dataframe to value of a list

Tags: list, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to declare a dataframe for each element of a list with the name of the dataframe being the element of the list. For instance i have:

```
liste
Out[205]: ['Modele', 'TypeJours', 'Historique', 'Temp']
```

and I would like to have something like:

```
Modele = pd.DataFrame()
TypeJours = pd.DataFrame()
```

and so on.
Do you have any idea how i can perform such a thing with python? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`globals().update({ df_name : pd.DataFrame() for df_name in lst})`

You could update globals with a dict comprehension, creating an empty df for each entry in a list. Not sure if this is a good practice.